# 3 way mortgage, need judges decision to sorting out ownership

Tags: united-kingdom, mortgage

I bought house with partner (A) & friend (B).  Partner (A) moved out after 1 year, (have document signing over their share to me) friend (B) lost job & moved out after 2 years.  After 25 years (now 27) cannot find (B) as mortgage (interest only) now finished.  I need to get Judge to take friend (B) off deed to sell or re-mortgage in my sole name.  All tenants in law. Believed that (B) moved to Texas, & deceased in 2008.
Solicitors have suggested getting the judge to take trustee (B) off deeds, on grounds of not being in country for over 12 months & not contributing to mortgage for 25 years.  Lenders have put mortgage "on hold" with me paying monthly payments until this is sorted. How can I get in front of a judge to make this order? Without using a solicitor.

Comment: You need a solicitor.

Comment: You're looking for a "quiet title action", that is, a lawsuit to quiet the title. If you want to be able to sell the property at some point in the future you will have to prove to the buyer that you've done it right. This is not a DIY project.

Comment: great info on the "quiet title action" ... good one.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that term doesn't exist in UK law, but I'm not sure what the equivalent is. I suspect you want law.stackexchange, not money.